# azure web app capture post data parameters

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Someone is sending lots of traffic to my new web app at name.azurewebsites.net  I am receiving lots of http post requests to this site.

I need to see those post parameters. I have already tried to get that data in FREB logs in my portal. Any other way to see post data parameters coming to azure web app.

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage FREB to get the detailed events and notifications from the various modules that work on the client request during its life-cycle. Also, you could leverage [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions/) to diagnose requests in your web apps. Here is a screenshot of my web app:

[image]

**Note:** The request details don't include the data sent to your app in a POST call by default. You could [Install Application Insights SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net/) in your app and add code to call `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TrackTrace()`, then your could see the detailed POST data in Application Insights. For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions/) about custom tracing and log data and how to see request POST data with Application Insights.